# How to take test results while using Dataprovider and save it in excel in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to save result of an calculator operation in an excel sheet but I am not able to think a logic of how to iterate the row and column based on the number of testcase. (I think i am not able to explain properly)

Comment: Please add some detail.  Show your working and logic so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Apache POI library for that, see - https://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html